# Need alarmManager or workManager?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am doing an app in Kotlin for my university and the concept is that the user taps a button, at the same time data enters a database and at the end of the day, the app congratulates or "punishes" the user, comparing today data list size to yesterdays.

My entity only has `val date: Date`, i copied the **@TypeConverter** from [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data) to convert date to long. In my DAO i use

```
@Query ("SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE date BETWEEN: from AND: to")
    fun findConsumption(from: Long, to: Long): List<User>
```

to see if works and every time i tap the button data enters as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GNWP.jpg) and i can retrieve, with the DAO, data and find data list size to compare.

The problem, where i need your help, is: **(1)** I need to look to alarm manager or workManager for the app to get data and the user get result, at the end of the day or a time deadline, everyday?
**(2)** How can i create the mechanism when the date is long integer?

Comment: What do you want to acheive?

Comment: Hi @JimaleAbdi, i want at the end of the day if the size of today data list that includes converted dates to long is bigger than yesterday, and that i want to do it everyday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question #1, I believe you are expecting to run the query at specific time, I think you should use `AlarmManager` due to currently `WorkManager` may only be set to run periodically instead of in a specific time.

As for #2, the simplest way is to use time in millisecond, i.e.

```
val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

or if you have a date type already

```
val curDate = Date()
val curMillis = curDate.time
```